# Python π = 1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) - (1/5) + (1/6) + (1/7) + (1/8) + (1/9) - (1/10) ...1748 Euler

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, primes, numerical-methods

I wrote this code to show that my [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/cihfeu/this_euler_series_for_%CF%80_is_beautiful_and/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) is correct.

> After the first two terms, the signs are determined as follows: If the denominator is a prime of the form 4m − 1, the sign is positive; if the denominator is a prime of the form 4m + 1, the sign is negative; for composite numbers, the sign is equal the product of the signs of its factors.
>
> Basically it's the harmonic series minus the non-Gaussian prime reciprocals and reciprocals which factors are an odd multiple of the non-Gaussian primes- beautifully embodying [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

This is a very, very inefficient way to calculate π. However, I believe it's the most beautiful. Which is a hard sell, because π algorithms are pretty much the most harmonious things.

This formula for π is my favorite because it clearly shows how a circle is related to the harmonic series, and how that series is related to the prime number theorem and quadratic reciprocity.
I love all algorithms for π, this is for its 'insight' it provides in relating π, primes, and quadratics.

Something to note is that swapping the logic here from n%4==1 to n%4==3 results in the sum = π/2 , and converges a bit faster.

```
import decimal
iters = int(input('Number of Iterations: '))
D = decimal.Decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
s = D(0)
for x in range(1, iters):
    clist = [int(i) for i in prime_factors(x)]
    plist = [n for n in clist if n%4==1]
    if len(plist)%2!=0:
        s-=1/D(x)
    else:
        s += 1/D(x)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Minor mistake, but it will hurt you sooner or later if you are not cautious: you ask the number of iterations, then loop on `range(1, iters)`, which has length iters-1 (`range(a, b)` contains values from a to be **excluding b**. So, the loop should be on `range(1, iters + 1)`

Comment: Nice catch! Merci!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought the series for PI alternated signs with each term.

Comment: You're thinking of the Leibniz series my friend :) There are alot of series for pi.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: if you alternate signs on each term, the sum is log 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are approximating is
$$ \pi =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{s(m)}}{m},$$
where \$s(m)\$ counts the number of appearances of primes of the form \$4k+1\$ in the prime decomposition of \$m\$, compare

- [How can we prove \$\pi =1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots\,\$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434313/42969)

on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

The computation of the factor \$ (-1)^{s(m)} \$ can be done more efficiently: Instead of creating a list of all prime factors of \$m \$, then filtering the list for prime factors of the form \$4k+1\$, and finally counting the filtered list, you can compute the sign while factoring the number:

```
def sign_for_pi_series(n):
    """ Returns sign for 1/n in the pi series.

    The sign is -1 if n has an odd number of prime factors of the form 4k+1,
    and +1 otherwise.
    """
    s = 1
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            if i % 4 == 1:
                s = -s
    if n > 1 and n % 4 == 1:
        s = -s
    return s
```

The summation then simplifies to

```
sum_pi = sum(D(sign_for_pi_series(x))/D(x) for x in range(1, iters + 1))
print(sum_pi)
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Blank lines

You require 2 blank lines before `def` statements to be [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant.

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100


def prime_factors(n):
```

#### Whitespace

You have your operators written as follows:

> ```
> len(plist)%2!=0
> ```

You should use whitespace around operators instead:

```
 if len(plist) % 2 != 0:
```

#### Refactored

```
import decimal
iters = int(input('Number of Iterations: '))
D = decimal.Decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100


def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors


s = D(0)
for x in range(1, iters):
    clist = [int(i) for i in prime_factors(x)]
    plist = [n for n in clist if n % 4 == 1]
    if len(plist) % 2 != 0:
        s -= 1 / D(x)
    else:
        s += 1 / D(x)
    print (s)
```

Comment: Sorry, your review is not useful at all.

Comment: @stefan apology accepted

Comment: I would also put a blank line between import and the rest of the code. Not sure if it is somewhere in PEP 8 or no, though. Also, you introduced a space on the last line which shouldn't be there.

Comment: @stefan - How is this not useful?  There are code standards for a reason.  In any case, +1.

Comment: I almost thought you speak python but seeing the first comment... you probably thought the same :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, I do try from time to time o_O https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A200620+%5Bpython%5D+OR+%5Bcython%5D

Answer (score 5):

You don't need plist, only its length. Likewise, you don't really need to build clist, its values would be enough, making `prime_factors` a generator. You may also remove the `if`.
Note that given the extremely slow convergence, it's really not useful to compute with 100 decimals, so you could use floats instead.

```
import decimal

iters = int(input('Number of Iterations: '))
D = decimal.Decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100


def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            yield i
    if n > 1:
        yield n

s = D(0)
for n in range(1, iters + 1):
    k = sum(1 for p in prime_factors(n) if p % 4 == 1)
    s += (-1)**k / D(n)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Good point about the convergence, I shall simplify when I share this algorithm. I had been comparing 6 different Pi algorithms when writing this one and needed the precision there :) I shall share that project here too.